# Chef tutorial errors on node configuration [cannot load such file -- mysql2]

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

So here is the weird part. I'm using the `ubuntu-14.04` platform for my `test kitchen` setup, and I'm **also** using `bento/ubuntu-14.04` for my vagrant node.

They should be the same right? I'm basically following the Chef tutorial [Manage a Web App](https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/ubuntu/get-set-up/), and `kitchen` passes perfectly; but when I deploy to the node using `knife ssh localhost --ssh-port 2222 'sudo chef client' ...etc...` it stops with the following:

```
localhost Recipe: awesome_customers_ubuntu::database
localhost   * mysql_database[my_company] action createIgnoring mysql2-0.3.17 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.17
localhost
localhost
localhost     ================================================================================
localhost     Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_database[my_company]'
localhost     ================================================================================
localhost
localhost     LoadError
localhost     ---------
localhost     cannot load such file -- mysql2
```

So I have 2 questions.

1. How do I solve this?
2. Why is this happening, if both kitchen and my node are bento-based?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the mysql2_chef_gem first before calling mysql_database

```
mysql2_chef_gem "default" do
  gem_version "0.4.4"
  action :install
end
```

Somehow your TK node has gotten that installed.

Comment: I solved it by purging everything and re `berks install`. Somehow, something broke and the command returned a ComunnitySiteError.

Comment: The community site had a production outage earlier today, probably wasn't related to anything you did :)